# Cannot fetch data from localhost using Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, cors, svelte-3, sveltekit

In a new Sveltetkit project, I'm trying to fetch rest API from my local backed:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load() {
        const url = `http://127.0.0.1:9000/v1/articles`;
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }
            });

        if (res.ok) {
            let articles = await res.json()
            console.log('res is:', articles);
            return {
                props: {
                    articles: articles
                }
            };
        }

        return {
            status: res.status,
            error: new Error(`Could not load ${url}`)
        };
    }
</script>
  
  <script>
    export let articles;
    
  </script>

 
<h2>List of articles</h2>

{#each articles as dastan}
  <h4>{dastan.title}</h4>
{/each}}
```

I can see the json response being printed in the server's terminal However I get this error in browser:

```
500
Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at load (http://127.0.0.1:3000/src/routes/articles/index.svelte:188:20)
    at Renderer._load_node (http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:953:37)
    at Renderer.start (http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:536:29)
    at async start (http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:1207:15)
```

And this error in the chrome's console

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/v1/articles' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Despite  allowing all origins in the backend server ([in go gin](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors)) and adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` to request above I could not remove this CORS problem. So I have no clue what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. Actually I should not have put `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` in the request header. CORS is taken care of, if server is peroperly configured to allow the origin. In my case I just had to user cors middleware in gin:

```
r.Use(cors.Default())
```

Here is the working solution if sveltekit:

```
 <script context="module">
  export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9000/v1/articles');
    const articles = await res.json() ;
  if (res.ok) return { props: { articles: articles } };
  return {
    status: res.status,
    error: new Error()
   };
  }
</script>
  
  <script>
    export let articles = [];    
  </script>

 
<h2>Articles</h2>
 
{#each articles as article}
   <h4>{article.title}</h4>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have to setup the backend to use CORS midlleware.
In an express BE the command would be `app.use(cors())` after you install the package named `cors`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Or use something similar for the environment you're working on.

Comment: Well I don't use express, but as I said, in my backend (in go gin) I've already set up the server to accept cors from all origins.

Answer (score 0):

###### Note to self

1. When fetching, make sure to **prefix the URL with `http://`** e.g. `await fetch('http://localhost:3000')` unless you need to [set HTTPS for localhost](https://web.dev/when-to-use-local-https/).
2. Unless you [allow CORS for all domains/origins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests), make sure to **include the *port* in [CORS configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors)** if the origin uses a *port* since [it is considered to be of the same origin if and only if the *protocol*, *host* and *port* are exactly the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).